# checkbox value inserted in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm struggling now for a few days to get the value of a checkbox in my code.

Basically I have an admin-page where the customer can select and deselect images that will put online.

You can select and deselect images that will be shown on the homepage, and separate on the gallery-page. Both checked is also possible.

I have another checkbox that can be selected to remove the image from the list(image_deleted). 
There is still a database entry and the images are still on file-system but later on I'll create a cleanup-job.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    ob_start();

    require('../../lib/dbconnection.php');
    require("../../lib/checklogin.php");
    require("includes/upload.inc.php");

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM gallery where image_deleted != 1 order by id desc';
    $result=$conn->query($query);
    $count=$result->num_rows;

    ?>      
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Classic Nails - CMS</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <meta name="description" content="ClassicNails">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/screen.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/libs/magnific-popup.css"> 
            <script src="../js/libs/min/jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../js/min/custom-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script> 
            <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
                            type:'image',
                                    gallery:{
                                            enabled:true
                                    }
                            });
                    });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php include('includes/header.inc.php'); ?>
            <?php include('includes/nav.inc.php'); ?>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <article class="content">
                    <h1>Foto gallery</h1>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($uploadResult)) {
                    echo "<p><strong>$uploadResult</strong></p>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadImage" id="uploadImage">
                        <p>
                                <label for="image">Upload image:</label>
                                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo MAX_FILE_SIZE; ?>" />
                                <input type="file" name="images" id="imagesd" /> 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                                <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload" />
                        </p>
                    </form>
                        <div id="maincontent">
                            <h2>Foto informatie</h2>
                            <form name="FotoInformatie" id="fotoInformatie" method="post" action="">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center"><strong>Foto<strong></td>
                                        <td align="center"><strong>Titel</strong></td>
                                        <td align="center"><strong>Beschrijving</strong></td>
                                        <td align="center"><strong>Homepage</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    while ($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="hide" align="center"><?php $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                                        <td><a href="../img/uploads/<?php echo $rows['filename'];?>" class="image-link"><img src="../img/thumbs/<?php echo $rows['filename']; ?>"></a></td>
                                        <td align="center"><input name="title[]" type="text" id="title" value="<?php echo $rows['title']; ?>"></td>
                                        <td align="center"><input name="caption[]" type="text" id="caption" value="<?php echo $rows['caption']; ?>"></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxHome[]" id="checkBoxHome" value="<?php echo ($rows['home'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4" align="center">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form> 
                        </div>
                    </article> <!-- end of content -->
                </div> <!-- end of container -->
            <?php include('includes/footer.inc.php'); ?>
        </body>
    </html>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $caption = $_POST['caption'];
        if ($_POST['checkboxHome'] == "") {
            $checkboxHome[] = '0';
        } else {
            $checkboxHome[] = '1';
        }
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            $result1=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE gallery SET title='$title[$i]', caption='$caption[$i]', home='$checkboxHome[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'");
            header("location:/admin/foto-admin.php");
            }
    }
    ?>
```

The checkbox only works on the first row in my DB. When I select another record, only the first record in my db will be updated.

Another issue is that my checkbox won't be checked so I don't know based on my screen when a image is online or not. in the database I see a 1 of a 0.

I know that sql-injection is possible and I have to prepare the statements, but that is the next step when I get this checkbox-issue working.

Hope someone can help me with my code. It's giving me a headache.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages back?

Comment: I get no errors displayed.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but how do i display the value when a checkbox is submitted on post?

Comment: You'd do something like `if(isset($_POST['variable'])){ echo $variable;}`

Comment: I got nothing when I submit a checkedbox. no error.

Comment: try print_r($_POST['checkboxHome']) or print_r($_POST) for printing all values in $_POST

Comment: the first give me an error:Notice: Undefined index: checkboxHome. The other give me an array() back..

Answer (score 1):

**Check these**

```
Attribute name="id[]" for id field is not given. And it should get inside 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $id = $_POST['id'];
    }
```

**Incorrect spelling in getting Post value**

change

```
$checkboxHome = $_POST['checkboxHome']; 
$checkboxFotoboek= $_POST['checkboxFotoboek']; 
$checkboxDelete = $_POST['image_deleted'];
```

to

```
$checkboxHome = $_POST['checkBoxHome']; 
$checkboxFotoboek= $_POST['checkBoxFotoboek'];
$checkboxDelete = $_POST['checkboxDelete'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get wrong value.

Your check-box name is `checkBoxHome` and you are trying to get `$_POST['checkboxHome']` instead of `$_POST['checkBoxHome']` .

Try `$_POST['checkBoxHome']` and print it as `print_r('checkBoxHome')`

Same mistake in `checkBoxFotoboek` check-box.

Comment: Not exactly. I'm testing all kinds of code because I want to know what I get returned from the variable. I now can select the first entry and in the database, I see a 1 in the column when I checked that box. When i check the box of the second row, the first row will be updated instead off the second. I think that my loop is not working correctly. I'll update my question with my new code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $caption = $_POST['caption'];
    $checkboxHome = $_POST['checkBoxHome'];
    $checkboxFotoboek= $_POST['checkBoxFotoboek'];
    $checkboxDelete = $_POST['checkboxDelete'];
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $result1=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE gallery SET title='$title[$i]',   caption='$caption[$i]', home='$checkboxHome[$i]', fotoboek='$checkboxFotoboek[$i]', image_deleted='$checkboxDelete[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'");
        header("location:/admin/foto-admin.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I've tried by didn't help. I;m now testing other code-lines but still doesn't work.